# libsvm fails for very small numbers with error code 'Wrong input on line'

Tags: libsvm

I've tried searching the internet for inputs on this one, but ineffectively.

I am using libSVM (https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and I've encountered this while training the SVM with rbf kernel.

If a feature contains very small numbers, like feature 15 in the following

```
0 1:4.25606e+07 2:4.2179e+07 3:5.1059e+07 4:7.72388e+06 5:7.72037e+06 6:8.87669e+06 7:4.40263e-06 8:0.0282494 9:819 10:2.34513e-05 11:21.5385 12:95.8974 13:179.117 14:9 15:6.91877e-310
```

libSVM will fail reading the file with the error code `Wrong input at line <lineID>`.

After some testing, I was able to confirm that changing such a small number to 0 appears to fix the error. i.e. this line is correctly read:

```
0 1:4.17077e+07 2:4.12838e+07 3:5.04597e+07 4:7.76011e+06 5:7.74881e+06 6:8.91813e+06 7:3.97472e-06 8:0.0284308 9:936 10:2.46506e-05 11:22.8714 12:100.969 13:186.641 14:17 15:0
```

Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening? My file contains a lot of number around that order of magnitude.

I am calling the SVM via terminal on Ubuntu like:

```
<path to>/svm-train -s 0 -t 2 -g 0.001 -c 100000 <path to features file> <path for output model file>
```

Comment: Please notice: the second error message turns out to be printed by the remainder of my code (explicitly by std:: cpp stuff, so at first I wasn't able to figure it out). I've edited the original post accordingly